# PHP - How to show restaurant bookings

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I currently have a database of reservations for a restaunt. This contains the menu of what they want. This is what my sql query shows and what I want to show on my website
[image: Database]

This shows two orders, and all the menu items of each order. I want to show these as two separate orders on my website.
My PHP code for this is as follows using PDO, excluding the database connection and the query etc.

```
        $resultset = $conn->query($query, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        while($result=$resultset->fetch())
        {
                echo "Order Details:<br> CustomerID: $result->CustomerID<br>PaymentID: 
$result->PaymentID<p>
        Booking Details:<br> Date: $result->Date<br> 
    Time: $result->Time <p>Menu Items:<br>";

            echo "$result->MealName x$result->Quantity<br>";
        }
    ?>
```

However, this just outputs the website as so;

```
Order Details:
CustomerID: 1
PaymentID: 1
Booking Details:
Date: 2016-01-22
Time: 21:00:00

Menu Items:
Mexican Rib Eye Steak x2
Order Details:
CustomerID: 1
PaymentID: 1

Booking Details:
Date: 2016-01-22
Time: 21:00:00

Menu Items:
Mexican Mess x2
Order Details:
CustomerID: 1
PaymentID: 1

Booking Details:
Date: 2016-01-22
Time: 21:00:00
```

I only want the customerID/PaymentID displayed once per order, with all the items underneath.

How Would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to group by reservation id, since a customer can place more than one order on the same day. That said, I'd order the query by customer id then reservation id. Then adjust your loop so that it detects when reservation id changes from what it was on the last iteration. When it does, output the customer information. Something like this:

```
$last = null;
while (...) {
    if ($result->ReservationID !== $last) {
        // output per-order header
    }
    // output item details
    $last = $result->ReservationID;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do it in two steps -- first get the list of orders for today, then for each, display the detail. This is a more object-oriented approach. You'd have to write a class for each object. For example:

```
$restaurant = new Restaurant($id);
foreach ($restaurant->getOrdersForDate($today) as $order) {
    $order->render();
}
```

Where the Order::render() method would look something like:

```
public function render() {
    $this->renderHeader();
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $item->render();
    }
    $this->renderFooter();
}
```